# CSS Некорректно отображаются картинки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

В видео-уроке тот же код, и отображаться он должен так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вместо этого, у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(надеюсь отличие надписей и картинок не критично)

```css
.about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.about_item {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <div class="about_item">
    <div class="about_img">
      <img src="assets/image/About/Star.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about_item">
    <div class="about_img">
      <img src="assets/image/About/Mjolnir.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about_item">
    <div class="about_img">
      <img src="assets/image/About/Batcar.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, что ширина изображений превышает ширину элемента .about-item. Чтобы ограничить ширину изображения по ширине родителя - указываем для него max-width: 100%. В css выглядеть это должно примерно так:

```
.about_item img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Да вы просто гений!

Comment: Вовсе нет! это стандартный прием

Comment: Я просто пошутил